# Why we can't call servlet constructor instead of init method to initialize the config parameters?

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

Why can not we call servlet constructor instead of init method to initialize the config parameters?

Answer (score 0):

By [specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafi.html):

> The lifecycle of a servlet is controlled by the container in which the
>   servlet has been deployed. When a request is mapped to a servlet, the
>   container performs the following steps.
>
> If an instance of the servlet does not exist, the web container
>
> 1. Loads the servlet class.
>
>    1.1. Creates an instance of the servlet class.
>
>    1.2. Initializes the servlet instance by calling the init method.
>      Initialization is covered in Creating and Initializing a Servlet.
> 2. Invokes the service method, passing request and response objects.
>      Service methods are discussed in Writing Service Methods.

Comment: This is how the servlet works. Not why the servlet is initialized with an init instead with a constructor with arguments.

Answer (score 0):

`Servlet` is an interface.

An interface **can't define constructors**.

This is the reason why it has been defined an `init` method to call after the instantiation of the servlet. There was no other possibility to initialize the `Servlet` passing a `ServletConfig`.